# CriteriaBuilder don't paste function parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

This is hibernate query which I get from CriteriaBuilder:

```
select generatedAlias0 from MyObject as generatedAlias0 where 1=1 order by COLLATION_KEY(lower(generatedAlias0.mycol), :param0) asc
```

The `:param0` should be parsed as `UCA400R1` but it is parsed as `:param0`. Where is the problem?

```
cb.function("COLLATION_KEY', String.class, cb.lower(orderExpression), cb.literal("UCA400R1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is driven by `LiteralHandlingMode`, which has 3 settings:

**AUTO**
Criteria queries uses bind parameters for any literal that is not a numeric value.  This is the default behavior if configuration is not explicitly specified.

**BIND**
Used to increase the likelihood of JDBC statement caching, you might want to use bind parameters for numeric values too. The `BIND` mode will use bind variables for any literal value.

**INLINE**
mode will inline literal values as-is. To prevent SQL injection, never use `INLINE` with String variables. Always use constants with the `INLINE` mode.

To adjust the default setting, set `hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode` accordingly.

Comment: And how do you adjust the literal handling mode? by passing `hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode=INLINE` in properties file or somehow in java code?